# Trigger on Update of a specific field in mySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to replicate the `Username` field in my database. Specifically I was looking to add/remove the `Username` across different tables, whenever the row that contains `Username` is added inside `UserDatabase`. To that end, I was thinking of using the trigger mechanism.

I am thinking along the lines of:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'addUsername' AFTER INSERT ON UserDatabase FOR EACH ROW
    IF (UPDATE(Username))
        BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO anothertable (Username) VALUES ('NewUser');
        END
```

My question is that is how do I capture the updated `Username` from `UserDatabase` and replicate it into `NewUser`? And also, is there a way to remove `FOR EACH ROW` as I only want the loop to run once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html):

> Within the trigger body, you can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases OLD and NEW. OLD.col_name refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. NEW.col_name refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.

And no, you can not remove `for each row` and I think you misunderstood it a little. There actually is no loop. `for each row` refers to multiple rows in your insert or update statement. When you add multiple users with one insert statement, you want all of them replicated, right? Not just one.

Then you should note, that there's a difference between single-quotes and backticks. Backticks should be used, if a column or tablename or whatever includes characters that shouldn't be there, like a space, or if the name is actually a reserved keyword. Single-quotes, like you used them for the trigger name are used to tell MySQL it's a string.

Your trigger should look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'addUsername' AFTER INSERT ON UserDatabase 
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO anothertable (Username) VALUES (NEW.Username);
```

For an update statement, you have to create another trigger.